# Dynamic Identifiers for Resources

Tags: rest

My company wants to do dynamic identifiers for resources.  Some folks somehow think this will make us more secure in the long run if identifiers for resources are unique on a given "session".

I'm trying to come up with reasons not to do this.  Although I'm certainly open to the idea if it actually makes sense.  I was reading Roy Fieldings dissertation in particular [Section 5.2.1.1](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_2_1_1) and was trying to figure out why we would go against the idea of having a static identifier for our resources.

Has anyone gone down this path and either love or regret the choice?

Comment: This sounds like security through obscurity, a concept that can't work.

Comment: I agree with you.  I'm being told by security folks that it is to avoid people guessing other people's resources and to make replay harder even though we are talking about retrieving identifiable resources